# Skeletons keep on spawning above bed

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

**This is the old (2014-2015) version of Minecraft Xbox, I may even forget some details as this was long ago**

There is a house at the back of the Village and a bed is contained inside. However a skeleton keeps on spawning on top of the bed. The weird thing is, it keeps on repeating. I sleep, skeleton spawns, I kill skeleton, I sleep and the same loop is repeated.

So...

What is this strange phenomenon

I would also like to add that it seems to only happen at that house

[image: The house of the... SUPAH SPOOKY SKELETONS]

Comment: Is the house properly lighted inside? Gotta make sure it's _lit_

Comment: Yep It is lit...

Comment: @GuynamedJon What about roof? Is it lit? Arent there halfslabs? Maybe he falls trough slabs on roof on ur bed?

Answer (score 3):

- Is the house properly lit?
- Is there a cave right underneath it? (you gotta dig under and find out)
- Is there a mob spawner underneath it? (you gotta dig under and find out)
- Is the roof made out of half-slabs? - Make it out of stairs instead.
- Last but not least, ***nuke it with DYNAMITE***, that'll sure fix all your problems as there won't be a house (or bed) to worry about...